# Excel 2016, "{}" disappearing in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've modified an existing template called "Daily Schedule". For some reason, all of the cell formulas have "{}" around them. When I click into the cell to edit the formula, the "{}" disappears. After this occurs, the formula doesn't work anymore for the entire column, even if I haven't changed the formula.

Example:

> =IFERROR(INDEX(tblData,MATCH(C$5+$B7&ShowName,tblData[DATE & TIME]&tblData[WHO],0),3),"")

...which is initially displayed as...

> {=IFERROR(INDEX(tblData,MATCH(C$5+$B7&ShowName,tblData[DATE & TIME]&tblData[WHO],0),3),"")}

...until I click on it. Once I've entered into the formula it loses the "{}" and once I press enter any and all data that was displayed in the column of the table is now gone, even if I don't modify the data, table, or function.

Why does this happen?

My goal is to use this formula

> =IFERROR(IF($H$3="All",INDEX(tblData,MATCH(D$5+$B7,tblData[DATE & TIME],0),3),INDEX(tblData,MATCH(D$5+$B7&ShowName,tblData[DATE & TIME]&tblData[WHO],0),3)),"")

... so that I can either display tasks for certain dates/times for one category (i.e. anna for the template as is) or for all of the categories at once by selecting "all" in the drop down menu. I've simply eliminated the parts of the function that deal with names and included a separate "who" named "all," then put it in the "value if true" part of an if statement. Like I said, this part works alright, but the initial formula part does not.

The first part of this formula (the "value if true" part) works and displays all of the dates when I select "all" in the drop down menu, but the second part ("value if false") does not work when I select any of the other categories that do not equal "All", even though it is the exact same formula from the untouched template.

Comment: Those are "array" formulas.  They work on a range of cells instead of individual cells.  The braces don't show in the formula edit window.  The system adds the braces to the cell display when you enter the formula as an array formula by using ctrl-shift-enter instead of enter.  If you click on an array formula and then resave it with enter, it gets saved as a regular formula.  You can re-resave it as an array formula.

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid... I couldn't find anything on google for the life of me... if only I would've know that's what it was called. It works perfectly now, thanks again.